# How to prevent Screen Capture in Android without using Secure Flag?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, screen

I am working on 1 application for Video chatting where I need to implement the following functionalities.

1. During video chat if anyone tries to capture a screenshot of the screen then he can able to take a screenshot but at that time I need to show a warning popup message and report to the admin.
   But if I use "Secure Flag" then it will prevent taking screenshots but I can't able to show a warning popup message and report to a user.
2. Similar way if anyone tries to capture screen recording then can't able to record and we can show warning popup.

By using "Secure Flag" we can prevent taking screenshots and screen recording but we can't get any event and due to that we can't show warning popup messages.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for the way to prevent screen capture and screen recording for other reason. The secure flag prevent, also, screen mirroring too. I look forward to get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those are possible, sorry. Your app is not informed about apps using the media projection APIs, which includes any device-supplied screenshot/screencast tools.